# Yii2 - How can I add a search in Dropdownlist Widget

Tags: yii2

Good day!

How can I add a **search** on a **dropdownlist**?

I want a dropdown search like the **Select2 widget**.

Dropdownlist:

```
<?= $form->field($modelRis, "[{$i}]lib_item_item_id")->dropDownList(
ArrayHelper::map(LibItem::find()->orderBy('item_description')->all(), 'item_id', 'item_description'),
[
    'prompt'=>'Select Item',
    'onchange'=>'
            var tmp = $(this).attr("id");
            var thisId = tmp.split("-");

            var tmp2 = "";
            var tmp3 = "";

            var sample_id = $(this).val();

            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['online-requisition/listsofunit?item_id=']).'"+$(this).val(),
            function( data ) {
                $( "#risrequesteditem-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_unit_id").html( data );

                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_item_item_id").val( sample_id );

                tmp2 = data;
                tmp3 = tmp2.split("=====");
                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-available_stock").val( tmp3[1] );
            });
        ',
    'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
    ],
])->label('Item',['class'=>'label-class']); ?>
```

I can't use the select2 widget because the **'onchange'** or this line of code is not supported:

```
'onchange'=>'
            var tmp = $(this).attr("id");
            var thisId = tmp.split("-");

            var tmp2 = "";
            var tmp3 = "";

            var sample_id = $(this).val();

            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['online-requisition/listsofunit?item_id=']).'"+$(this).val(),
            function( data ) {
                $( "#risrequesteditem-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_unit_id").html( data );

                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_item_item_id").val( sample_id );

                tmp2 = data;
                tmp3 = tmp2.split("=====");
                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-available_stock").val( tmp3[1] );
            });
        ',
```

Thanks...

Updates:

If i'm going to used the select2 widget in order to have a search function during the selection of items there will be a problem.

**In the :**

**first selection** its working:

And the **onchange function** has been working also. And automatically fill all the data in form field (Item no, Unit and StockAvailable) after the selection of item.
[1st Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mD7e.jpg)

**second selection** is not working:
But I can select an item. Only the jquery function onchange is the problem... 
[2nd Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvg6J.jpg)

Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. What exactly is your problem and what you would like achieve?

Comment: Thanks, how can I add a **search** on a **dropdownlist** widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Ajith above, you should use the Yii2 Select2 Widget from http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

If you go through the details you will find that the above widget does allow you to add event handlers by using the `pluginEvents` parameter settings of the widget.

```
pluginEvents = [
"change" => "function() { log('change'); }",
"select2:opening" => "function() { log('select2:opening'); }",
"select2:open" => "function() { log('open'); }",
"select2:closing" => "function() { log('close'); }",
"select2:close" => "function() { log('close'); }",
"select2:selecting" => "function() { log('selecting'); }",
"select2:select" => "function() { log('select'); }",
"select2:unselecting" => "function() { log('unselecting'); }",
"select2:unselect" => "function() { log('unselect'); }"
```

];

Although it's not possible to provide proper code without knowing the context etc of your code snippet, however it can be re-written using Yii2 Select2 widget as below (the code below is untested, but should give you an idea of the structure):

```
use kartik\widgets\Select2;

$data = ArrayHelper::map(LibItem::find()->orderBy('item_description')->all(), 'item_id', 'item_description');

// Usage with ActiveForm and model
echo $form->field($modelRis, "[{$i}]lib_item_item_id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Item'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'select2:select' => 'function(e) { 
            var tmp = e.target.id; 
            var thisId = tmp.split("-");

            var tmp2 = "";
            var tmp3 = "";

            var sample_id = e.target.value;

            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['online-requisition/listsofunit?item_id=']).'"+$(this).val(),
            function( data ) {
                $( "#risrequesteditem-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_unit_id").html( data );

                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-lib_item_item_id").val( sample_id );

                tmp2 = data;
                tmp3 = tmp2.split("=====");
                $( "#loop-"+thisId[1]+"-available_stock").val( tmp3[1] );
            });
        }
        '
    ],
]);
```

Please note I have used `select2:select` as the event handler.

I had to provide this as a separate answer because I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Comment: thank you @sm1979 but when I used the select2 widget and added the plugin events in that widget, the change function in the event is not loaded, i don't know why.. I'm going to update my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yii2 select2 widget` for this purpose. There is good documentation with demos available at

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

An example usage with active form is given below

```
// Usage with ActiveForm and model
echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,// the select option data items.The array keys are option values, and the array values are the corresponding option labels
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
         'change' => 'function(){// write your on change code here}'
     ]
]);
```

Comment: tnx for the reply.. but i can't use the select2 widget because i don't how to add onchange function in that widget... I'm going to update my post with the full code of dropdownlist..

Comment: In the documentation of Yii2 select2 widget there is a property called pluginEvents where you can write select2 jquery events as mentioned by @sm1979.For your code you have to use the change event for this purpose .I have edited my answer to include the change event

Comment: thank you so much @Ajith I really appriciate you're help.. but when I used the select2 widget and added the plugin events in that widget, the change function in the event is not loaded, i don't know why.. I'm going to update my post..